# Backspace and arrow keys not working in vi editor

Tags: 12.04, vi

The backspace is unable to erase the characters. The navigation keys produce alphabets.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If `update alterantives --list editor` shows that the vi editor in reality is vim.basic then I guess that this has to do with character translation at some layer. The most likely place to encounter problems is in a SSH-client like Putty if such is being used to access the console. If so then check Puttys settings and choose your correct translation - probably utf8. If vim.basic is not listed in the output then simply try to install Vim.

Answer (score -1):

You should see in the [vi & vim forum](http://vi.stackexchange.com)

Anyway, there is a thread that can help you: [Backspace does nothing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/backspace-does-nothing)

Comment: Why not just give the answer instead of links to follow?